# I am trying to utilize an API but i am unsure what needs to be called to append to the document

Tags: jquery, ajax, api

this is my code , I'm trying to take the date used from the api to retrieve the bitcoin price but i've been lost for quite sometime. please help. this is the documentation: https://bitcoincharts.com/about/markets-api/

```
var userDate = $("#userDate").val();
          var bitcoinApiUrl = "http://crossorigin.me/http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".btn").on("click", function(){



          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: bitcoinApiUrl,
            success: function(currency) {
              // for(var i = 0; i < currency.length; i++) {
                console.log(currency);
              // }
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert("something went wrong man!")
            }
          });

          });
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
        $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

currency is a string!! Not an object.
You should transfer it to JSON.
For example.

```
success: function(currency) {
  var temp = JSON.parse(currency);
  for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    console.log(temp[i].latest_trade);
  }
},
```

I wrote a demo,
http://jsbin.com/paremi/edit?html,js,console,output

Hope it helps.